# Embedding mathjax in my documentation does not render colors properly

Tags: mathjax

I have a documentation written in sphinx/RST which contains formulas rendered with MathJax. The documentation uses a dark theme (white text on black background).

With the default path for the MathJax CDN (no custom mathjax_path set), the rendering is perfect.

I tried to embed mathjax by downloading the latest distribution on mathjax.org. I have extracted it into _static/mathjax, and set the mathjax_path to:

```
mathjax_path = 'mathjax/MAthJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
```

After building the documentation html with sphinx, the mathjax installation was properly copied to the build dir in _static, and the html script has changed from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_static/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

The equation is rendered (so the path is correct), but in black (on black background), only the fraction bars are white.

What can be wrong?

Comment: There's not much to go on but check if webfonts are being blocked (so MathJax falls back to PNGs for "fonts").

Comment: Peter's suggestion is probably correct, you are getting the image fonts.  Are you using Firefox, and viewing the document locally (from a `file://` url)?  If so, you may be hitting Firefox's same-origin restriction, which won't let it load fonts from a directory that isn't a subdirectory of the one containing the HTML file.  If that is the case, then installing the MathJax fonts or the STIX fonts locally (as system fonts on your computer) should resolve the issue for you.